# Python no actualiza el valor de la base de datos con PyMySQL

Tags: mysql, python, python-3.x

**Código**:

```
import discord
import asyncio
from PyMySQL import pymysql

# Código sin importancia
if message.content.startswith('!points'):
    clist = message.content.split(' ')
    if len(clist) > 1:
        # Código sin importancia
    else:
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM usuario where discord_id = "+str(message.author.id))
        bdb=cursor.fetchall()
        print (bdb)
        for usuario in bdb:
            puntos=usuario[3]
            await client.send_message(message.channel, content=('Tienes '+str(puntos)+' puntos!'))
```

Estoy usando los modulos de [discord.py](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py), asyncio y [PyMySQL](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyMySQL) en Python3.5. Un script diferente suma puntos en la base de datos cada 10 segundos.
Hay mas código, pero básicamente lo que hace es detectar nuevos mensajes en discord que empiecen por *!points*, y luego comprueba si solo ha mandado *!points* o si ha mandado *!points [algo]*.

**Problema**:

El problema viene cuando mandan solo *!points* (en el `else:`). Hace la búsqueda `cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM usuario where discord_id = "+str(message.author.id))`. Y termina sacando la cantidad de puntos que tiene la persona.
La primera búsqueda la hace perfectamente, y manda los puntos que tiene esa persona en ese exacto momento, pero **las siguientes veces que pones *!points*, el valor es siempre el mismo valor que salio la primera vez**.

Supongo que el error esta en estas lineas

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM usuario where discord_id = "+str(message.author.id))
bdb=cursor.fetchall()
```

¿Como podría arreglar el error que he dicho? ¿Hay mejores maneras de hacer la búsqueda?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He encontrado la solución. Tienes que añadir `db.commit()` al final del `else:`, que quede asi:

```
else:
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM usuario where discord_id = "+str(message.author.id))
    bdb=cursor.fetchall()
    print (bdb)
    for usuario in bdb:
        puntos=usuario[3]
        await client.send_message(message.channel, content=('Tienes '+str(puntos)+' puntos!'))
    db.commit()
```